# AWS Cloudformation: Outputs ServiceName for Unnamed ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I create ECS stack via cloudformation. Everything works fine.
Due to a certain reason, I do not specify ServiceName for ECS service (Name: Service) in definition.
However, I want to have it in outputs, after Cloudformation creates the stack.
So for this purpose, I defined outputs like this:

```
Outputs:
  ECSServiceName:
    Description: Service Name I want to see
    Value: !GetAtt Service.ServiceName
```

When I run update CF Stack, I receive an error from AWS:

```
Requested attribute ServiceName must be a readonly property in schema for AWS::ECS::Service
```

Does this mean that I cannot receive it in outputs, if it wasn't strictly specified before? Or I made a mistake somewhere in Outputs definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) `ECSServiceName` from your template. Also the correct way to get ECS service name is `!GetAtt Service.Name`:

```
Outputs:
  ECSServiceName:
    Description: Service Name I want to see
    Value: !GetAtt Service.Name
    Export:
      Name: ECSServiceName
```

Then, in other templates,  you can use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to reference the exported output:

```
!ImportValue ECSClusterName
```

Comment: What if I do not need to use it in another template, I just want to see this in the "Outputs" section in my Cloudformation stack?

Comment: @Kname I updated the answer. The correct way to get the name is `!GetAtt Service.Name`, not `!GetAtt Service.ServiceName`. Off course you don't need export if you don't want to reference it from other stacks.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I changed ServiceName to Name and that helped! Have a great day.